# I am getting "Input String not in given format" Error for Id value for doing entry in my text file

Tags: c#

I am getting error for this line me.Id = int.Parse(cols[0]); to do entry in my text file.
I am parsing my string but it is giving blank string "" when I am debugging the file.
Can anyone help me regarding solving the file

```
public static List<MatchupEntryModel> ConvertToMatchupEntryModels(this List<string> lines)
    {
        //id = 0, TeamCompeting = 1, Score = 2, ParentCompeting = 3
        List<MatchupEntryModel> output = new List<MatchupEntryModel>();

        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
            string[] cols = line.Split(',');

            MatchupEntryModel me = new MatchupEntryModel();
           
            me.Id = int.Parse(cols[0]);
            
            if(cols[1].Length == 0)
            {
                me.TeamCompeting = null;
            }
            else
            {
                me.TeamCompeting = LookupTeamById(int.Parse(cols[1]));
            }
            
            me.Score = double.Parse(cols[2]);

            int parentId = 0;
            if(int.TryParse(cols[3], out parentId))
            {
                me.ParentMatchup = LookupMatchupById(parentId);
            }
            else
            {
                me.ParentMatchup = null;
            }

            output.Add(me);
        }
        return output;
        //List<PersonModel> output = new List<PersonModel>();

        //foreach (string line in lines)
        //{
        //    string[] cols = line.Split(',');

        //    PersonModel p = new PersonModel();
        //    p.Id = int.Parse(cols[0]);
        //    p.FirstName = cols[1];
        //    p.LastName = cols[2];
        //    p.EmailAddress = cols[3];
        //    p.CellphoneNumber = cols[4];
        //    output.Add(p);
        //}
        //return output;


    }
```

I am also sending the my save entry to file function which is used for saving the file.

```
public static void SaveEntryToFile(this MatchupEntryModel entry, string matchupEntryFile)
    {
        List<MatchupEntryModel> entries = 
        GlobalConfig.MatchupEntryFile.FullFilePath().LoadFile().ConvertToMatchupEntryModels();

        int currentId = 1;

        if(entries.Count > 0)
        {
            currentId = entries.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).First().Id + 1;
        }

        entry.Id = currentId;
        entries.Add(entry);

        List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        //id = 0, TeamCompeting = 1, Score = 2, ParentCompeting = 3
        foreach (MatchupEntryModel e in entries)
        {
            string parent = "";
            if(e.ParentMatchup != null)
            {
                parent = e.ParentMatchup.Id.ToString();
            }
            string teamCompeting = "";
            if(e.TeamCompeting != null)
            {
                teamCompeting = e.TeamCompeting.Id.ToString();
            }
            
            lines.Add($"{ e.Id }, { teamCompeting }, { e.Score }, { parent }");
        }

        File.WriteAllLines(GlobalConfig.MatchupEntryFile.FullFilePath(), lines);
        //foreach (TeamModel t in models)
        //{
        //    lines.Add($"{ t.Id }, { t.TeamName }, { ConvertPeopleListToString(t.TeamMembers)}");
        //}

        //File.WriteAllLines(fileName.FullFilePath(), lines);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the text file you're trying to read in? Or at least the portion you're having trouble with?

Comment: If you're trying to parse CSV, there are multiple free and excellent packages to do it.

Comment: MatchupEntryModel.csv       

1,1,0,
2,2,0,
3,3,0,

I should get number 4 in my first field but it is not parsing the string

Comment: Use `int.TryParse` instead. What is the string that is erroring?

Comment: Can I manually write in  my textfile

Comment: How would you get `4` out of the data `1,1,0, 2,2,0, 3,3,0,`? Obviously your csv file does not look like you expect it to. But unless you  show it, nobody can help you ...

Answer (score 0):

Use TryParse instead of Parse. It will return 0 instead of throwing exception.